# Understanding Python decorators

Tags: python, decorator

I wrote a small piece of code to run it myself and understand the flow:

```
def perform_arithmetic_ops(func):
    print("INSIDE PERFORM ARTITHMETIC")
    def decorate(*args):
        print("I JUST GOT DECORATED")
        print(f"SUM -> {args[0]+args[1]}")
        func(args[0],args[1])
    return decorate


@perform_arithmetic_ops
def print_me(x,y):
    print(f"X = {x} ; Y = {y}")

print_me(5,4)
```

Please correct me if my understanding, which I've summarized in the form points below, is incorrect.

1. `def perform_arithmetic_ops` is the decorator which only takes a callable object, in this case a function as its argument, correct?
2. The inner function `def decorate()` here is what actually performs the desired modification. What I noticed was commenting `func(args[0],args[1])` inside `def decorate()` basically meant that the `X={x} ; Y={y}` statement wasn't being printed. So does this mean that the the decorator replaces everything the original function does? If yes, how is that a modification? Isn't it more of a replacement for another function?
3. `return decorate()` i.e. calling `decorate()` instead of returning it led to errors for tuple index out of range. Why?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. You're wrapping the function, not modifying it, so if you don't call it you won't see the expected results. 3. Because you're calling it with empty `args`, so it doesn't have what it needs to pass to the wrapped function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe,  thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a good look at this enormous [answer/novel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators/1594484#1594484). It's one of the best explanations I've come across.

> `def perform_arithmetic_ops` is the decorator which only takes a callable object, in this case a function as its argument, correct?

Yes. You are right about it.

> The inner function `def decorate()` here is what actually performs the desired modification. What I noticed was commenting `func(args[0],args[1])` inside `def decorate()` basically meant that the `X={x} ; Y={y}` statement wasn't being printed. So does this mean that the the decorator replaces everything the original function does? If yes, how is that a modification? Isn't it more of a replacement for another function?

A `decorator` is a function that takes a function as its only parameter and returns a function. This is helpful to “wrap” functionality with the same code over and over again. It is wrapping but not modification.

> `return decorate()` i.e. calling `decorate()` instead of returning it led to errors for tuple index out of range. Why?

**To understand decorators, you must first understand that functions are objects in Python.**

Because you might be calling it without any parameters. Try this `return decorate(5,1)`. But after this statement and if you try to decorate function like `print_me`, then `print_me` might be holding non-callable object. See this:

```
def perform_arithmetic_ops(func):
    print("INSIDE PERFORM ARTITHMETIC")
    def decorate(*args):
        print("I JUST GOT DECORATED")
        print(f"SUM -> {args[0]+args[1]}")
        return func(args[0], args[1])
    return decorate(5, 1)


@perform_arithmetic_ops
def print_me(x,y):
    print(f"X = {x} ; Y = {y}")
    return 5


# print_me(5,2) # Will throw: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
print(print_me)
```